# How to move files listed in a text file to related directories?

Tags: shell, loops, unix, text, move

I have a text file containing the list of files like this:

```
A file1.gz file2.gz
B file3.gz file4.gz
C file5.gz file6.gz
D file7.gz file8.gz
...
```

`A,B,C,D, ...` are the name of the samples which are located in the first column and I want to make subdirectories with the name of the samples and move related files (located in second and third columns) of each samples to its own directories. How can I make a loop for doing this?

Comment: What you are calling "batch file" is just a text file containing a list/table of items; a [tag:batch-file] is a text file that constitutes a script using Windows command prompt commands...

Comment: please enter your code by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35826790/edit) link and also show whats expected and what errors you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the fields in your `textfile` are seperated with spaces (and your dirs and filenames have no spaces), you can use

```
while read -r dir file1 file2; do
   mkdir -p "${dir}"
   if [ ! -d "${dir}" ]; then
      echo "Something strange with ${dir}, I do not know what to do."
      exit 1
   fi

   if [ -f "${file1}" ]; then
      mv "${file1}" "${dir}"
   fi

   if [ -f "${file2}" ]; then
      mv "${file2}" "${dir}"
   fi
done < textfile
```

This will work with a fixed nr of columns. When you want to support an unknown nr of files on each line, you must change this a bit:

```
while read -r dir files; do
   mkdir -p "${dir}"
   if [ ! -d "${dir}" ]; then
      echo "Something strange with ${dir}, I do not know what to do."
      exit 1
   fi

   for file in ${files}; do
      if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
         mv "${file}" "${dir}"
      fi
   done
done < textfile
```

Comment: edited the first solution: changed file1 into file2 in last part.